# How to get the log of Ping via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm still new to PowerShell,

May I ask about how to write the script to get the result from ping the IP address?

& I'm using **Test-Connection** command.

[image]

Comment: Just use the redirection operator: `ping 8.8.8.8 > pinglog.txt`

Comment: @mjsqu I'm using TestConnection in PowerShell Script

Comment: Then this is what you need: `$TestResults = Test-Connection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8`. You haven't made it clear what you want to do with the result, but you can then use `$TestResults | Get-Member` to see what you can extract from the results.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah - PLEASE do not post pictures of text to a _text and code oriented site_. you make it difficult to read AND difficutl to use your picture for testing code ... [*grin*]

Comment: Please clarify what is is you want the output to look like. Something looking **exactly** like what you get when performing `ping 8.8.8.8` in a cmd console or???

Comment: [Ping via Powershell, log results with timestamp](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/337701-ping-via-powershell-log-results-with-timestamp)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

after that I found from Internet,

You only need to add

```
Tee-object -FilePath C:\Users\engsooncheah\Desktop\PS\Aport2_log.txt
```

**Sample code**

```
$TestResults = Test-Connection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8 -Count 10| Tee-object -FilePath C:\Users\engsooncheah\Desktop\PS\Aport2_log.txt
```

Comment: Before putting a bounty on your question next time, please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). With the information provided in your question (were you neglect to tell that you want to **both** file *and* display the results), there is no way somebody would understand you looking for this answer.

Answer (score 8):

**If** you want to mimic the **Exact** output of the ping command in a console, then the easiest way would be:

```
$temp = New-TemporaryFile
ping 8.8.8.8 > $temp.FullName
$result = $temp | Get-Content -Raw
$temp | Remove-Item -Force

# Output on screen
$result
```

However, if you want to get this exact same output style using the `Test-Connection` cmdlet, there's a lot more work to be done.
Here's a function that outputs like the `ping` command would do:

```
function Format-TestConnection {
    # mimic the **Exact** output of the ping command using Test-Connection
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [int]$Count = 4
    )
    # build output
    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine("Pinging $ComputerName with 32 bytes of data:")

    # perform Test-Connection and capture the results
    $success = 0
    $responseTimes = @()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
        $startTime = (Get-Date).Millisecond
        try {
            $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -BufferSize 32 -ErrorAction Stop
            [void]$sb.AppendFormat("Reply from {0}: bytes={1} time={2} TTL={3}", 
                                    $ComputerName, $ping.ReplySize, $ping.ResponseTime, $ping.TimeToLive)
            [void]$sb.AppendLine()
            $success++
            $responseTimes += $ping.ResponseTime
        }
        catch {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine("Request timed out.")
            $responseTimes += ($startTime - (Get-Date).Millisecond)
        }
    }

    [void]$sb.AppendLine()
    [void]$sb.Append("Ping statistics for $ComputerName")
    [void]$sb.AppendLine(":")

    $lost =  $Count - $success
    $pct  = '{0:N0}%' -f (($lost / $Count) * 100)
    [void]$sb.Append("    Packets: Sent = $Count, Received = $($success), Lost = $lost ($pct loss)")

    if ($success) {
        [void]$sb.AppendLine(",")
        [void]$sb.AppendLine("Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:")
        $min = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
        $max = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
        $avg = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Average).Average

        [void]$sb.AppendFormat("    Minimum = {0}ms, Maximum = {1}ms, Average = {2}ms", $min, $max, $avg)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine()
    }
    else {
        [void]$sb.AppendLine(".")
    }

    # return the formatted output
    $sb.ToString()
}

# use the above function like
Format-TestConnection -ComputerName "8.8.8.8" -Count 4
```

Output on screen:

> ```
> Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=8 TTL=80
> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7 TTL=80
> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7 TTL=80
> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=8 TTL=80
>
> Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
>     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0,00% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 7ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 8ms
> ```

If this is **NOT** what you are asking for, then please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57567079/edit) your question and show us the desired output, because the question is unclear about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in a variable.

```
$result = Ping 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Test-Connection $Server | Select-Object * # To get which information you are interested in, then include them in the below script.

```
$server = 'Server'
test-connection $server  | format-table @{n='TimeStamp';e={Get-Date -Format yymmddhhmmss}},__SERVER, Address, ProtocolAddress, ResponseTime |`
 out-file c:\log\test-connection.txt -append
```

Test this script, then modify your output as per your needs.

Comment: Can I change the Test-Connection to" test-Connection $Server ErrorAction Stop " ?

Comment: Yes, by using **Do** , **while** , make sure to define the status at the beginning of **DO**, then while condition will be the negative status. i.e $server_status ='Alive' , **while** $server_status ='notAlive'

Comment: How about Ping statistics? Lost = 0 (0% loss) ?

Comment: -For that you have to define the count variable , then do a math between the successful packets vs none.
- Totalcount - successful = unsuccessful then do the percentage.

Comment: I would do select | export-csv.

Comment: How about TCP Ping?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is if you can ping the server, you can just use Test-Connection and check whether its got a value

```
$result = Test-Connection server.domain.tld
if( $result ){
  "Server is available"
} else {
  "Server is unreachable"
}
```

However, `Test-Connection` has been superseded by `Test-NetConnection` which is far more versatile. At it's most basic usage though, usage is similar to `Test-Connection`, but even a failed test will return an object so you'll want to check the `PingSucceeded` property value in this case:

```
$result = Test-NetConnection server.domain.tld
if( $result.PingSucceeded ) {
  "Server is available"
} else {
  "Server is unreachable"
}
```

Regardless of whether you use `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection`, you can inspect the returned members for each by calling them and inspecting the methods and properties on the returned object like so (note that `gm` is an alias for `Get-Member`):

```
Test-Connection | Get-Member
Test-NetConnection | gm
```

This is useful because you can then know what properties you can operate on and know which values to check that you care about.