# PING results to CSV

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell scripting. My goal is to output the ping results of different servers from a .txt file to a csv file. I found relevant articles, but they were not helpful as they just output whether the host is UP or DOWN. I want to obtain the results with detailed ping statistics as I get when I ping from the Command Prompt.

Can anybody, please help me in doing this.

Below script that I used, just outputs whether the host is reachable or not.

```
$names = Get-content "C:\Users\surya\Desktop\computers.txt"

foreach ($name in $names){
      if (Test-Connection -Delay 15 -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
       $Output+= "$name,up"
       Write-Host "$Name,up" -ForegroundColor Green
      }
      else{
        $Output+= "$name,down"
        Write-Host "$Name,down" -ForegroundColor Red
      }
    }
$Output | Out-file "C:\support\result.csv"
```

Comment: I have removed all of your invalid tags, this is clearly a [[tag:powershell]] question, acting on a single file, and has absolutely nothing whatsover to do with the [[tag:shell]], [[tag:batch-file]], [[tag:cmd]], or [[tag:batch-processing]] tags you included.

Comment: Why did you decide then to re-add the [[tag:batch-processing]] tag? you are not processing a batch of anything, _(unless you're trying to imply that each line/computer is a batch of the text file content!)_, you have a single file you're parsing, not a batch of files!

Comment: @SimaPaul - when you run `Test-Connection` to ONE target system and save that to a $Var, what stats do you want to keep? you can see what is available via `$Var | Get-Member` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of my [Format-TestConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639191/9898643) function and use that in the loop.

Put the Format-TestConnection function on top of your script and beneath that put:

```
$names = Get-Content "C:\Users\surya\Desktop\computers.txt"
$Output = foreach ($name in $names) {
    Format-TestConnection -ComputerName $name -Count 1
}

# display on screen
$Output 

# write to file
$Output | Out-File "C:\support\pingresult.txt"
```

The above however will not give you a CSV file.
Based on the Format-TestConnection function, here's another function that outputs a (collection of) PSObjects that you can use to output a proper CSV file:

```
function Get-ConnectionStatistics {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [int]$Count = 4
    )
    # prepare output
    $obj = [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName         = $ComputerName
        Status               = $null
        BytesSent            = 32
        BytesReceived        = $null
        ResponseTime         = $null
        TTL                  = $null
        PacketsSent          = $null
        PacketsReceived      = $null
        PacketsLost          = $null
        MinimumRoundTripTime = $null
        MaximumRoundTripTime = $null
        AverageRoundTripTime = $null
    }

    # perform Test-Connection and capture the results
    $received = 0
    $responseTimes = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
        $startTime = (Get-Date).Millisecond
        try {
            $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -BufferSize 32 -ErrorAction Stop
            $obj.Status        = "OK"
            $obj.BytesReceived = $ping.ReplySize
            $obj.ResponseTime  = $ping.ResponseTime
            $obj.TTL           = $ping.TimeToLive

            $received++
            $ping.ResponseTime
        }
        catch {
            $obj.Status = "Request timed out."
            ($startTime - (Get-Date).Millisecond)
        }
    }

    $lost =  $Count - $received
    $pct  = '{0:N0}%' -f (($lost / $Count) * 100)
    $obj.PacketsSent     = $Count
    $obj.PacketsReceived = $received
    $obj.PacketsLost     = "$lost ($pct loss)"

    if ($received) {
        $obj.MinimumRoundTripTime = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
        $obj.MaximumRoundTripTime = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
        $obj.AverageRoundTripTime = [int]($responseTimes | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    }

    # return the object
    $obj
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$names = Get-Content "C:\Users\surya\Desktop\computers.txt"
$Output = foreach ($name in $names) {
    Get-ConnectionStatistics -ComputerName $name -Count 1
}

# output on screen
$Output | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$Output | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\support\pingresult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.  At least test-netconnection works the same in ps5 & ps7.

```
$names = 'yahoo.com','microsoft.com'
$names | % { test-netconnection $_ } | select computername,pingsucceeded |
  export-csv result.csv

WARNING: Ping to 40.113.200.201 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Ping to 13.77.161.179 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Ping to 104.215.148.63 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Ping to 40.76.4.15 failed with status: TimedOut
WARNING: Ping to 40.112.72.205 failed with status: TimedOut


cat result.csv

#TYPE Selected.TestNetConnectionResult
"ComputerName","PingSucceeded"
"yahoo.com","True"
"microsoft.com","False"
```